Is performing Adharma better than performing inaction?
My question
Is taking the adharmic approach to fulfilling your duty better than not performing your duty at all? While I understand both adharma and inaction are not recommended, I am still curious to know, given the option between the two, which one is preferable? If action is preferable, then performing Adharma while being unattached to your actions and their fruits is alright i.e does not accrue sin?

GitaGPT says

In the teachings of the Bhagavad Gita, Adharma is considered to lead one into ignorance and is not higher than inaction. Instead, it is essential to perform one's duties (Dharma) to elevate oneself. Inaction does not fulfill one's obligations and can lead to negative consequences. Thus, it is better to act righteously than to remain inactive.


Relevant verses from the Gita
Krishna says,

Man does not reach actionlessness by not performing actions; nor does he attain perfection by mere renunciation. (3.4)


Therefore, do perform your allotted duty as action is superior to inaction... (3.8)


He who takes delight in the Self alone, is gratified with the Self, and is contented in the Self, has no duty. (3.17)


In this world that great soul has nothing to gain by action nor by abstaining from action... (3.18)


Having abandoned attachment to the fruits of the action, ever content, depending on nothing, he does not do anything even while being engaged in activity. (4.20)


To one who is devoid of attachment, who is liberated, whose mind is established in knowledge, and who works for the sake of sacrifice (for the sake of God), the whole action is dissolved. (4.23)


He who does actions, offering them to Brahman and abandoning attachment, is not tainted by sin, just as a lotus leaf is not tainted by water. (5.10)


For a sage who wishes to attain to Yoga, action is said to be the means; for the same sage who has attained Yoga, inaction is said to be the means. (6.3)


This question is arising because you don't realise that "Nobody can stay actionless".
How can you stay in inaction? Won't you move your body? Won't you attend the calls of nature? Won't your mind be engaged in mental action (thinking, desiring, speculating etc)? Won't you breathe? Won't you eat and drink? Won't you sleep and wake up?
When you are doing everything, how then can inaction be even attempted? The body will act, however hard you may attempt. Hence actionlessness is a myth till you identify yourself with the body. The mind will act, however hard you may attempt. Hence actionlessness is a myth till you identify with the mind.
Actionlessness in Gita is not refraining from action but a complete withdrawal of identification from action. The moment you get situated in your own true self, that is when you become actionless. You stop identifying with any action. You become absolutely silent while the body and mind act like a robot. You remain merely as a witness to all that.
To reach that, the first step Krishna says is to act as per your svadharma or performing duties without any expectations. This process gradually reduces the flow of mind and desires and takes you towards the ultimate realisation and actionlessness.
If you continue to identify with your actions and also with expectations of the actions, you will get a baggage of karma free. You may do Dharma, get rewards, enjoy the fruits and stay bound. You may do Adharma, get punished, suffer and stay bound. You asked, is it better to do Adharma being detached? The moment you have the thought of doing Adharma, you are attached then and there. Where is detachment? In the second case, the bondage strengthens, in the first it may weaken yet in both cases, you will remain bound to Samsara.
